# Flip image and stop at a certain angle

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have this CSS:

```
-moz-transform: scaleY(-1);
-o-transform: scaleY(-1);
-webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
transform: scaleY(-1);
filter: FlipV;
-ms-filter: "FlipV";
```

that flips and image upside down.
All I want is the image to stop when has flipped 90° and so it's invisible.

Is that possible in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your need is to flip and image by 90 degrees such that it becomes invisible then you should look at using `rotate(90deg)` transforms (`rotateX(90deg)` in this case) like in the below snippet.

I am not sure on when you would be making the element become invisible (like `:hover`, click etc) but if you make it invisible on `:hover` then put the `:hover` selector on a container element instead of the image itself. This is because once the image is hovered and becomes invisible due to rotation then the mouse pointer is technically no longer over the image (in other words, `hover`  is no longer applicable). This would mean that the image immediately reverts back to original state automatically.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #777;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
img {
  transition: all 1s;
}
div:hover img {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/nature/1" />
</div>
```

---

On the other hand if you are insistent on using `scaleY()` transform to achieve this effect, then you would have to use `scaleY(0)` in-order to make the element invisible. `scaleY(-1)` will always end up at -180deg and there is no way to stop this in the middle.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #777;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
img {
  transition: all 1s;
}
div:hover img {
  transform: scaleY(0);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/nature/1" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-flip.php

Take a look at this demo from great David Walsh :)

I think for you the vertical flip is more interesting

Just change the .front and .back @ :hover to 90deg and you get the result you want!